# jQuery append to src

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to refactor my existing code to now use jQuery and I can't      figure out how to append my info to my src

Here was my existing line:

```
document.getElementById("itemDetail").src = detailUrl;
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
$("#itemDetail img src").append(detailUrl);
```

This is my snip of html:

```
<div id="detailsPane">
  <img src="images/blank-detail.jpg" width="346" height="153" id="itemDetail" />
</div>
```

Comment: `$("img#itemDetail").attr('src' , detailUrl);`

Comment: append or set/replace src (fomr the look of your original js, you are replacing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your selector should be `$("img#itemDetail")`

**>** If you need to set src you can use

```
$("img#itemDetail").attr('src' , detailUrl);
```

**>** If you need to append to the src you can use

```
$("img#itemDetail").attr('src' , $("img#itemDetail").attr('src') + detailUrl);
```

Answer (score 3):

use `attr`

example:

```
$(this).attr("src", src);
```

you can see more in http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: This is how to replace, **not** how to append to "src".

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

```
detailUrl = 'image.png';
$("#itemDetail").attr('src', detailUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
document.getElementById("itemDetail").src = detailUrl;
```

in jQuery is:

```
$('#itemDetail').attr('src'...
```

you need

```
$('#itemDetail').attr('src',function(i,e){
    return e+=detailUrl;
})
```